# Refused to execute script in Ionic PWA

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I'm building an Ionic progressive web app. I am getting the errors as below:

```
(index):1 Refused to apply style from
'http://localhost:8100/build/main.css' because its MIME type
('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME
checking is enabled. vendor.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server
responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) main.js:1 Failed to load
resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):31 service worker installed (index):1 Refused to apply style
from 'http://localhost:8100/build/main.css' because its MIME type
('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME
checking is enabled. vendor.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server
responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (index):1 Refused to
execute script from 'http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js' because
its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type
checking is enabled. main.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server
responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (index):1 Refused to
execute script from 'http://localhost:8100/build/main.js' because its
MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type
checking is enabled. (index):1 Refused to apply style from
'http://localhost:8100/build/main.css' because its MIME type
('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME
checking is enabled.
```

I have my index.html as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Beauty of soul</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps (remove if not needed) -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  un-comment this code to enable service worker
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.error('Error', err));

    }
  </script>

  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
       It contains all of the dependencies in node_modules -->
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

  <!-- The main bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

My service-worker.js is:

```
/**
 * Check out https://googlechromelabs.github.io/sw-toolbox/ for
 * more info on how to use sw-toolbox to custom configure your service worker.
 */


'use strict';
importScripts('./build/sw-toolbox.js');'
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.0/firebase-messaging.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.0/firebase.js');


firebase.initializeApp({
  // get this from Firebase console, Cloud messaging section
  'messagingSenderId': '' 
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('Received background message ', payload);
  // here you can override some options describing what's in the message; 
  // however, the actual content will come from the Webtask
  const notificationOptions = {
    icon: '/assets/imgs/logo.png'
  };
  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});


self.toolbox.options.cache = {
  name: 'ionic-cache'
};

// pre-cache our key assets
self.toolbox.precache(
  [
    './build/main.js',
    './build/vendor.js',
    './build/main.css',
    './build/polyfills.js',
    'index.html',
    'manifest.json'
  ]
);

// dynamically cache any other local assets
self.toolbox.router.any('/*', self.toolbox.fastest);

// for any other requests go to the network, cache,
// and then only use that cached resource if your user goes offline
self.toolbox.router.default = self.toolbox.networkFirst;
```

I am integrating the Firebase push notifications so my firebase-messaging.ts is:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { FirebaseApp } from 'angularfire2';
// I am importing simple ionic storage (local one), in prod this should be remote storage of some sort.
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseMessagingProvider {
  private messaging;
  private unsubscribeOnTokenRefresh = () => {};

  constructor(
    private storage: Storage,
    private app: FirebaseApp
  ) {
    this.messaging = app.messaging();
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js').then((registration) => {
        console.log("inside navigation-----");
    this.messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);
    //this.disableNotifications()
    this.enableNotifications();
});
  }

  public enableNotifications() {
    console.log('Requesting permission...');
    return this.messaging.requestPermission().then(() => {
        console.log('Permission granted');
        // token might change - we need to listen for changes to it and update it
        this.setupOnTokenRefresh();
        return this.updateToken();
      });
  }

  public disableNotifications() {
    this.unsubscribeOnTokenRefresh();
    this.unsubscribeOnTokenRefresh = () => {};
    return this.storage.set('fcmToken','').then();
  }

  private updateToken() {
    return this.messaging.getToken().then((currentToken) => {
        console.log("heyyyyyy");
      if (currentToken) {
        // we've got the token from Firebase, now let's store it in the database
        console.log(currentToken)
        return this.storage.set('fcmToken', currentToken);
      } else {
        console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
      }
    });
  }

  private setupOnTokenRefresh(): void {
    this.unsubscribeOnTokenRefresh = this.messaging.onTokenRefresh(() => {
      console.log("Token refreshed");
      this.storage.set('fcmToken','').then(() => { this.updateToken(); });
    });
  }

}
```

Why I'm getting these errors ? Any idea?

Comment: Did you try restarting the whole serve?

Comment: I am trying it on Localhost

Answer (score 0):

Your service worker is trying to reach a file that does not exists. Make sure /build/main.css does exists.